# Show next two nodes of view inside the node

Tags: views, nodes

I have a list of nodes in a view from around 10 articles. if I click on the fifth linked article in the view, I see the whole article and I want to display on a sidebar the sixth and seventh article with a small picture and the title.

Does the Views module have the ability to do something like that, or do I have to write a preprocess hook where I query the view list, the current node, and sort it with i.e. date and pick the next two articles?